# How to get app dimension if size dependent on frame object?

Tags: python, tkinter

Too make it simple, i want to set window size with frame not geometry method. it return 1 uses **winfo_width** or 200 uses **winfo_reqwidth**. there's other method i can use to get root window size?

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

tkinter.Frame(root, width=640, height=360, bg="gray").grid()

print(root.winfo_width())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `root.winfo_reqwidth()`

Answer (score 0):

in your current script,at the time you called `winfo_width` the geometry info is not yet updated, thus it returns 1. You can force the update by calling `update_idletasks`

[winfo width window](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/winfo.html#M51)

> Returns a decimal string giving window's width in pixels. When a window is first created its width will be 1 pixel; the width will eventually be changed by a geometry manager to fulfill the window's needs. If you need the true width immediately after creating a widget, invoke update to force the geometry manager to arrange it, or use winfo reqwidth to get the window's requested width instead of its actual width

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

tkinter.Frame(root, width=640, height=360, bg="gray").grid()

# before update
print(f'before update: {root.winfo_width()}')

# force update
root.update_idletasks()
print(f'after update: {root.winfo_width()}')

root.mainloop()
```